# HREF attribute not working inside an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe to preview some data.

The data is stored in a javascript variable :

```
var s = '<html><head></head><body><a href="#">Hello_world</a></body></html>';
```

I am passing the data [`passing s`] to the iframe `SRC` attribute via Javascript.

Here is the code :

```
document.getElementById('output_iframe1').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(s);
```

So the data is loaded on the iframe except `<a>` elements.

`The Problem is` I can see `text` but not links. However, the element events are working fine(click,hover etc).

I inspected through Firebug and all are working well there.

I changed the `HREF` attribute to `http://somesite/file.html` on Firebug and amazingly it worked, but not with `#`.

Actually what i am doing wrong ??
Why i cant see `LINKS` without `http://` ?

Thank you .

Update 1 : I tested it with latest Firefox 8.0 and it works well,also checked with Google Chrome [Works well,but clicking on any links disappearing all the links],`Yeah as usual IE failed in all cases,it looks like IE doesn't know what is an Iframe`

Comment: start by correcting your first line of code. You might wanna use single quotes around your href attribute

Comment: @Pierre sorry it is a human error ,CORRECTED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use href="javascript:void(0)" instead of href="#".

OR

Since you are assigning it to a src attribute, you need to encode the string before you apply it. This is because, usually src value is url and "#" is used in browsers url sometimes. Hope you understand what I am saying.
Use encodeURIComponent() or encodeURI(). See the syntax here
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: So i need to find all `a` elements in the string and change `HREF` to something else ? what will happen if i use `javascript:void(0)` ? i have to work with click event with jQuery.

Comment: when u use javascript:void(0) you still can work with click event in jQuery.
I avoid giving href="#" everywhere in my code and make it javascript:void(0) and it works and also I can make any kind of manipulation freely with js or jQuery.

Comment: Okkey,let me try,but it works well with Firefox and Chrome[have some problems],how ?

Comment: what problems does chrome have?
Can you make a jsfiddle for that so that we can see it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jitheshkt/FvaSw/ - check this fiddle on firefox[work with ff 8.0 ,not working with 3.8],Google chrome[click on that link],and IE[MAD BROWSER].See the difference.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

```
var s = "<html><head></head><body><a href='#'>Hello_world</a></body></html>";
```

> Instead of This

```
var s = "<html><head></head><body><a href="#">Hello_world</a></body></html>";
```

Comment: Sorry its a Typing error[Please dont mind],see the updated Question.